# Convert decimal number provided in String to the binary

Tags: java, casting, binary

I want to convert a decimal number which is in the String format to the binary. For example I want to read `2` and output `10`.

I tried :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String dec;
dec = input.next();
int bin = Integer.parseInt(dec, 2);
System.out.println(bin);
```

I got the following error for the input 2:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2" under radix 2
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665)
    at binarytest.BinaryTest.main(BinaryTest.java:23)
```

Comment: `2` isn't a valid binary digit. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to convert a decimal number provided in the String format to binary.

Comment: Then you must parse it as decimal (base 10) and convert. I don't think there's builtin conversion in the JDK, you have to implement it yourself. Just to be sure, you want to read `2` and output `10`?

Comment: @knittl yes!...

Comment: You need to do it the other way around. You may use `input.nextInt()` to read the decimal number and then for example [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) to convert it to binary-

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the answer. It worked for me. First I converted the number in String format to integer and then used your solution to convert to binary.

Comment: It’s a good exercise in distinguishing between *a concept* and its *representation in the UI*. Here the number is the concept. In the UI it’s represented either as a decimal number (on input) or a binary number (on output). Use an `int` for the concept of a number and forget whether it’s binary, decimal or something else, those are implementation details not relevant to the task at hand. And apply the proper conversions on input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839796/convert-decimal-number-provided-in-string-to-the-binary/75839951#comment133775766_75839796), obtain an `int` from user:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
int input = scanner.nextInt() ;
```

And [convert to binary string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)).

```
String output = Integer.toBinaryString( input ) ;
```

To quote [another wise comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839796/convert-decimal-number-provided-in-string-to-the-binary/75839951#comment133776234_75839796) by Ole V.V.:

> It’s a good exercise in distinguishing between *a concept* and *its representation in the UI*. Here the number is the concept. In the UI it’s represented either as a decimal number (on input) or a binary number (on output). Use an `int` for the concept of a number and forget whether it’s binary, decimal or something else, those are implementation details not relevant to the task at hand. And apply the proper conversions on input and output.